# PHP - Class constructor behaving strangely

Tags: php, apache, class, object

I have written the following class in PHP

```
class animal
    {
    public $one ;
    public $two ;
    public $three ;

    public function __construct($one , $two , $three)
    {
         $this->one = $one ;
         $this->two = $two ;
         $this->three = $three ;
    }

    public function changefood($newfood)
    {
        $this->one = $newfood ;
        return $this->one ;
    }

    public function changeage($newage)
    {
        $this->two = $newage ;
        return $this->two ;
    }

    public function changejungle($newjungle)
    {
        $this->three = $newjungle;
        return $this->three ;
    }
}
```

Whenver I try to create an object of this class:

```
$animal1 = new animal ("bread" , "france" , 25) ;
```

I don't know why but throws these warnings:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for animal::__construct(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line 44 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line 9
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for animal::__construct(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line 44 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line 9
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for animal::__construct(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line 44 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: one in C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line
>   11
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: two in C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line
>   12
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: three in C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line
>   13

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? As I am a newbie and wasn't able to figure it out

Comment: Your code runs just fine: http://codepad.org/5aAPRxO7

Comment: then why it is throwing these warnings... plz let me know

Comment: Are you sure you copied your class exactly as it is. What version of PHP are you running, maybe it doesn't like that your function parameters are the same as the property names.

Comment: Are you sure, you are looking on the exact test script that produces the warnings?

Comment: @Barmar yes, it's the same class and I have tried that with different variable names but it still gives me these warnings and PHP version is 5.4.7

Comment: You must be doing something different, because it works for us in PHP 5.2, 5.3, and 5.4.

Comment: anyways thx for your kind attention....

Comment: Could you post the code file you construct the animal object in?